# Error throwing while substituting variable for version in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-2

I am getting an error while am substituting variables for the versions in the parent block in the pom.xml file.

For the properties tab, it's working fine, but when am changing the version to a variable that is being exported before '**mvn clean install**' in the parent block, the build is getting failed.

The error is shown below.

*"Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:${env.SPRINGBOOTVERSION} from/to abc-repos (https://continuousintegration.abc.com/artifactory/abc-repos): Illegal character in path at index 122: [https://continuousintegration.abc.com/artifactory/abc-repos/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/${env.SPRINGBOOTVERSION}/spring-boot-starter-parent-${env.SPRINGBOOTVERSION}.pom"](https://continuousintegration.abc.com/artifactory/abc-repos/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/$%7Benv.SPRINGBOOTVERSION%7D/spring-boot-starter-parent-$%7Benv.SPRINGBOOTVERSION%7D.pom%22)*

**Here the variables are not replaced for parent pom before the pom.xml gets resolved.**

---

Below is the code block of pom.xml which was substituted.

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>${env.SPRINGBOOTVERSION}</version> ---------> replaced version by variable
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

**The maven version here is 3.0.5 --- (Tried with 3.8.1 also for local build)**

Any solution to this will be helpful.

**FYI :**

*The variables are stored in a file in the below format.*

---> export SPRINGBOOTVERSION=1.2.3

*and then sourced to the shell by using the source command.*

> Also, the variables given in the properties block in the pom.xml are
> accepted by the maven, and it's working also. Only have a problem with
> the parent block here.

Comment: Really using Maven 3.0.5 ? Using 8+ year old software ...Also asking why do you like to use a variable the version here?

Comment: Even it's not working with 3.8.1, I have tried that one also while doing a local build.

Comment: for 3.8.1 also am getting the same error here

Comment: Simple answer to that is: Not possible. My questions keeps: What do you like to do that? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to store all the dependencies as variables in a file, so that, it's easy to change with respect to each version updated, so that, we need to change only 1 file, not the whole pom files.

Hence all the versions are added in the var.env file and are substituted in the pom.xml so that, if any change is there, we need to change only the var.env.

Comment: The dependencies are defined in pom.xml including their appropriate versions why do you like to have a separate supplemental file? Just change the version in pom.xml that's it... If you are changing the whole pom.xml just to change the version or adding/removing a dependency than this sounds like you are doing something wrong... Please show a full example what exactly is happening ?...
If we have only the versions in that supplemental file I don't see any advantage of that supplemental file...just use the pom file...that's it...

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you are setting the value for the substitution variable:

> SPRINGBOOTVERSION

In your environment somehow, I.e. as an environment variable in the shell that runs your command, and it’s not working?

Comment: Instead of a value in that place,  I have created a var.env and added all the dependencies here and have been calling this file "source var.env", so that it will get stored in the shell, and from there, the values of dependencies are getting updated in pom.xml

But her incase of parent block, it's throwing the above error.

Comment: OK, i understand. So you are running `source var.env` in a terminal and then running your maven command from that same terminal? It looks like the variable substitutions are not taking place then.

Comment: Exactly, that's the issue, but don't know why it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, maven will never ever support the behaviour you desire, the reason for that is when you are doing `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` maven deploys artifacts along with pom files into local or remote repository, but the information about your build environment (i.e. `${env.SPRINGBOOTVERSION}`) is stored nowhere, so, it is not a bug or lack of feature - maven just prevents storing invalid pom files in maven repository.

Comment: Here, I have stored all dependency versions in the var.env file and sourced it to the shell. 
In pom.xml in properties block, substituted variables are working, but here in parent block, it throws me an error above.

eg.

in var.env file

     export SPRINGBOOTVERSION=1.2.3

and this file is then sourced to the shell by the command, source var.env.

The values of version is stored in the shell.

Comment: Why do you store this information into an external file. The pom.xml is exactly the location and the purpose for this information...